# Realm.io deleting many objects takes too long

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have stored some chat data in realm, where I added > 40k objects for performance tests. The querying is fast, but the deleting takes too long and freezes the UI:

```
static func deleteMessagesForChatId(chatId: String) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("background", nil)) {

        let realm = try! Realm()

        let realmChatMessages = realm.objects(RealmChatMessage).filter("chatId = '\(chatId)'")

        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(realmChatMessages)
            print("message deleted from realm")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of try! realm.write try using:

```
realm.beginWrite()

realm.delete(realmChatMessages)

try! realm.commitWrite()
```

Comment: Thanks but what is exactly the difference?

Comment: It iterates over the list and deletes one object at a time in a transaction versus creating one transaction for all the deletes.

Comment: transaction means it does do it in a background thread? So I don't have declare it run in one myself?

Comment: I mean database transaction. It needs to block any other writes and then persist the changes to disk. There is a performance cost to do this. So in your case it would have to do that 40,000 times versus making all the changes and then persisting all 40,000 changes inside one transaction. I’ve pretty much switched all my code to use beginWrite/commitWrite from write because I had similar performance problems on add/update/deletes. Using begin/commitWrite waits until commitWrite is called to actually persist the changes all at once.

Comment: This difference claimed here doesn't actually exist. `write` is basically directly built on top of what `beginWrite` and `commitWrite` use, but allows to pass a closure instead. In both cases, you would end up with one transaction for all the deletes, what you should in general prefer because it has better performance characteristics.

Comment: I guess I didn't look far enough in the realm code. So if that is not the reason, then why is there such a large difference in performance?

Comment: So you're claiming to see a real measurable performance difference just by changing as you suggest in your answer? If so, could you share some more code around that, so that we can investigate that?

Comment: This isn't making a noticeable difference for us for about 50,000 objects.